# MFC CEdit control autocomplete

Tags: c++, autocomplete, mfc, cedit

I want to implement the autocomplete capability for the MFC's CEdit control but I couldn't find anything on the web.  I looked at the SHAutoComplete, but it seem like it's only useful for URL and file/folder path.

I was thinking of manually implement the function by programmatically display a popup menu at the blinking i-bar, but I encountered 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to get the xy coordinate of the blinking i-bar
2. I can't type anything after the popup menu is displayed

Can someone point me to an existing implementation that I can use?

Comment: Don't roll your own. Everything you need is already implemented for you. `SHAutoComplete` is just a very basic interface. You'll have to implement an `IAutoComplete` interface yourself to adjust the functionality to your needs (see [using autocomplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884.aspx) for details). Next time I find a machine with a real keyboard and real internet I'll see if I can put together a sample implementation.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't dig deep enough.  Thanks for the pointer.